# the results of my api (back end part) is not displayed in the front end part using reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

[image]
I am a beginner in nodejs and reactjs and I am developing a simple application. I am now in the front part, I installed all the necessary packages and modules. I launched my front part but nothing is displayed here is a screenshot of the result obtained. thank you in advance

And here a part of my code in reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'; 
import {fetchVideos} from '../actions/videoActions';
var listVideos
class videos extends React.Component { 
constructor(props) {
super(props); 
}

componentDidMount() { this.props.fetchVideos(); }

render() { 
if (this.props.data) {    
listVideos = this.props.videos.map(video => 
<li key={video._id}>
{video.titre}
</li>
);


}   
return (

<div>

<center><h1>All videos </h1></center>
{listVideos}   
</div>
)

}
} 

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
return {
clients : state.clients,
};
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
fetchVideos :()=> dispatch(fetchVideos())
};
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(videos);
```

Comment: Would you be able to post some of your code as well? We don't have enough information to be able to help with just a screenshot of the output.

Comment: Please submit some part of your FE code where the data is being fetched and attempted to be displayed

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: it gives the same result as the previous capture

Answer (score 1):

If you are using redux, probably you will need to map the `videos` in the `mapStateToProps` method

```
// ... 

componentDidMount() { this.props.fetchVideos(); }

// ...
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
return {
clients : state.clients,
videos: state.videos // HERE
   };
}
```

Note the `state.videos` param is got from the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

In your component, you are trying to read `videos` from its props. However, as Luiz mentioned, your `mapStateToProps` is only mapping the `clients` state variable to your component. `mapStateToProps` is the logic that binds redux state with your component props. So, assuming that you have set the `videos` object on your state (via [reducers](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers))  and adding the videos mapping on the `mapStateToProps` you should get said data on your component props.